# Is there a shortcut to create a new Wordpad document without automatically closing the one you are already working on?

Tags: windows-7, wordpad

I am using Windows 7. This seems like an obvious question but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Middle mouse click on the taskbar, if you have one, or open it from the start menu again?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried holding SHIFT and left click on the icon on the taskbar?

That should open another instance.

Answer (score 0):

type "start wordpad" in command line.